# How to load multiple images in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook

I have a folder filled with png images and I want to load them into my Jupyter notebook to form a training set. This question sounds simple; however, I can not find any methods of loading all my png images into my Jupyter notebook and use them for training.

Comment: This is not a jupyter specific question, it's a python question, right?

Answer (score 5):

Create a notebook in the same folder of your images,
paste this code in a cell. Then run it.

```
# collect all .png files in working dir
fs = !ls *.png

import IPython.display as dp

# create list of image objects
images = []
for ea in fs:
    images.append(dp.Image(filename=ea, format='png'))

# display all images
for ea in images:
    dp.display_png(ea)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scipy.misc.imread(name='my_file.png')`, this will return a Numpy array that you can then use to create a dataset.

You can see more information on the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html)

Imagining you have all your images in a folder called 'data' and the images are of format 'image_0.png, image_1.png, ...' your code could be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy 

n_images = 100 #Example value
image_names = ["data/image_{0}.png".format(k) for k in range(n_images)]

training_set = []
for img in image_names:
     training_set += [scipy.misc.imread(name=img)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a picture in a notebook by writing the following command in a markdown cell :

```
![alt text](fig1.png "figure one")
```

You could repeat this for each of your pictures.